# Cómo obtener el contenido del body de la página mas no el código fuente de la misma

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Estoy tratando de obtener el *¡Hola Mundo!* pero obtengo todo el código fuente de la página, ¿qué puedo hacer para solo obtener el resultado ya sea de este `document.write` o de un `alert`?

```js
$.ajax({
url: "data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPg0KPHRpdGxlPlNhbHVkbzwvdGl0bGU+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8Ym9keT4NCg0KPHNjcmlwdD4NCmRvY3VtZW50LndyaXRlKCLCoUhvbGEgTXVuZG8hIik7DQoNCjwvc2NyaXB0Pg0KDQoNCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=",
type: "GET",
success: (result) => {
console.log(result);
}
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: No está claro lo que quieres hacer. El código que has puesto no ayuda a entender el problema. Del "hola Mundo" no se sabe en que parte está,  ni como es tu página.

Comment: @JuanCarlosGuibovich con el ajax estoy obteniendo toda la estructura de la página y solo me interesa obtener el mensaje que arroje la página ese momento.

Comment: Tendrás que hacer un poco de web scrapping para obtener solo el mensaje "Hola Mundo"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes ocupar la función [load](https://api.jquery.com/load/)

```js
$("#contenido").load("data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPg0KPHRpdGxlPlNhbHVkbzwvdGl0bGU+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8Ym9keT4NCg0KPHNjcmlwdD4NCmRvY3VtZW50LndyaXRlKCLCoUhvbGEgTXVuZG8hIik7DQoNCjwvc2NyaXB0Pg0KDQoNCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

### Update

Según los comentarios, se requiere que se guarde en una variable.

La problemática es que la página que está en base64, tiene en su interior un script el cual usa `document.write` para imprimir texto en el cuerpo.

Una posible solución es sobrescribir la función `document.write` para que en vez que escriba algo, lo guarde en una variable

```js
const writes=[]; //un array donde se guardar todos los console.write, por si hay más de uno

let aux=document.write; //guardamos la funcion document.writ
document.write = (a) => writes.push(a); //sobreescribimos la función, ahora cada vez que se ejectue en vez de escribir algo, lo guarda en el array
  $(contenido).load("data:text/html;base64,PCFET0NUWVBFIGh0bWw+DQo8aHRtbD4NCjxoZWFkPg0KPHRpdGxlPlNhbHVkbzwvdGl0bGU+DQo8L2hlYWQ+DQo8Ym9keT4NCg0KPHNjcmlwdD4NCmRvY3VtZW50LndyaXRlKCLCoUhvbGEgTXVuZG8hIik7DQoNCjwvc2NyaXB0Pg0KDQoNCjwvYm9keT4NCjwvaHRtbD4=", ()=>{
  //esto se ejecuta cuando se carga el contenido
  
  document.write=aux; //restituimos al valor original document.write
  console.log(writes); //comprobamos que el array tiene los datos
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="contenido"></div>
```

Comment: Y cómo puedo hacer para 'guardar' ese texto en una variable y no cargarlo en un div

Comment: @code2018 Antes que eso, tu entiendes lo que está en ese "html"??

Comment: Según veo, un iframe

Comment: @code2018 No estimado, me refiero al código que tu tienes. tienes un HTML en base64, pero sabes lo que hay dentro de hmtl?

Comment: Si me puedes explicar para entender mejor sería de gran ayuda ya que no tengo tanta experiencia...

Comment: @code2018 entrá acá https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/142780/yussef

Comment: entré y no aparece nada

Comment: @code2018 te esperé largo rato, te esperaré 10min más

Comment: @code2018 Ahí creo que está